# How to Open pdf, ncx, opf files?

Tags: epub, pdf, calibre

I have an ebook downloaded from my university elearning site, **it was downloaded, not online reading**. But it can **only be opened and readed** from university's elearning app (android only, no iOS app for it) and the ebook can not be printed. I was stuck because i'm not used to read whole text book on android phone i want to print it or if i read the ebook, it should be on laptop or big screen desktop not small phone.

After looking up into file explorer inside my android phone, i figure out that the ebook that was downloaded **coming from either (or even both)**:

```
abcFolderName/123.epub
```

and/or

```
META-INF/container.xml
1.pdf
2.pdf
3.pdf
4.pdf
...
...
...and so on...
...
...
419.pdf
canbold.otf
canitalik.otf
canregular.otf
content.opf
mimetype
stylesheet.css
toc.ncx
*Note: all of those files above are contained in single .abcFolderName/ folder.
```

and somehow the provided university's elearning app **compile all of those files so it can be read from the app.**

This is what i've tried so far:

1. Converting `123.epub` to PDF -> ERROR when converting
2. Opening `123.epub` with various EPUB reader (lithium on android, calibre on computer, chrome epub reader on computer) -> SO FAR no luck, all return an error.
3. Opening single `1.pdf`, `2.pdf`, `3.pdf` and so on, one by one, with various PDF reader (on android and on computer) -> SO FAR no luck, all return an error.
4. Importing whole folder from Calibre software to make it (compile it) into single ebook -> SO FAR no luck at all.

I'm frustrated by this since the book is hundreds of pages and i cannot read it other than on my small android phone.

Please help me,
Thanks.

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: Can you still open the epub file in one of the epub readers (like Calibre Reader, or Readium or Adobe Digital Editions? If not, that means that the file is either corrupted or encrypted with some DRM protections that prevent reading in nonnative apps. Adobe Digital Editions has BOTH an android app and a Windows desktop client. Try to open it with that.

Comment: EPUB is in many ways a superior format to PDF. There is little need to export it to PDF. In fact, it is very strange that the epub file (which is basically just a zip file with the .epub extension) should even contain PDFs.

Comment: **@xcode:** Check the META-INF folder for an **encryption.xml** file. If it's present, the book is encrypted. 

Also check [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/aemmobile/supported-devices) whether the app uses the ADE RMSDK API. If it does, you should be able to download the book to your PC/Mac and remove the DRM.